# In-universe, how is BB-8's head adhered to his body?

Tags: star-wars, droids, the-force-awakens

In-universe, how is BB-8's head adhered to his body?

[image: Animated gif of BB-8 rolling past random garbage on Jakku.]

Comment: Haven't seen any material on it, but as an engineering problem, I'd approach it this way.  Gyroscopes inside the ball keep an orientation against which to rotate the body for motion.  Those same gyroscopes could keep an arrangement of magnets near the 'top' that suspend the 'head'.  So ..magnets.

Comment: [Magnets!](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/62687271.jpg)

Comment: [Duct Tape!](http://i.imgur.com/wvpKW6e.jpg)

Comment: The design of BB8 is so perfect.  Really captured the feel of droids in the classic trilogy; has an R2D2-ness about it while also being quite fresh and different.  ❤️

Comment: Downvotes why??  I don't get it!

Comment: Magnets: http://www.xkcd.com/413/

Comment: I removed the "before release" note which no longer applies, and indeed, provided an answer from official canon.

Comment: @b_jonas: thanks for the reminder. I've posted a [question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113823/is-bb-8-based-on-xkcd-413-new-pet) about that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add (and hopefully canonically replace?) Praxis's excellent answer: BB-8's head is held via magnetism using **magnetic casters**.

From *TFA Visual Dictionary*, we have both the explanation, and the diagram:

[image: Partial image of an annotated diagram of BB-8; the text appears below]

> ##### ALWAYS MOVING
>
> An internal orbiculate motivator rolls BB-8's body, while its head is kept perched atop the sphere with magnetic casters.  Wireless telemetry between the head and body removes the need to keep the head tethered to a single contact point.  When BB-8 needs extra stability or must traverse areas it can't roll through, it fires compressed liquid cable launchers that then reel the droid into hard-to-reach spots.

[image: Another partial image of BB-8, showing a cut-away of one quadrant of the spherical body. Among the visible annotations, "Magnetic caster" and its indicator line are circled (ellipsed?) in red. Another red circle highlights the caster itself, a spiral-wound cylinder about a sixth the height of the visible quadrant, mounted just inside BB-8's outer shell]

Comment: Good answer, DVK.  I fully expected that something more detailed than a pillow would arise after the film was released.  :-)

Comment: Is there any mention what would happen if BB8 would lose power? Just loosing the head would look like a design flaw...

Comment: @bdecaf: Quickening?

Comment: @DVK - Wouldn't that mean that his designation would be B-Oni-1?

Comment: @Richard: THWACK!

Answer (score 14):

## Magnets

As commenters have noted below the question, the obvious answer is **magnets**, but it was surprisingly hard to find an official confirmation of this.

The most common in-universe schematic of BB-8 that seems to be going around is the one directly below, which comes from a licensed card set. It unfortunately does not highlight the components or mechanism responsible for keeping the head attached to the body:

[image: line drawing of BB-8 in full side view with annotations identifying a few surface features. The drawing also has inset top and bottom views, unlabeled]

Branching out, I found this **licensed cushion** that is available, for example, at **[StarWarsBedroom.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20171013191352/http://starwarsbedroom.com/star-wars-rolling-bb8-droid-pillow)** (link redirected to archived version):

[image: Throw pillow with a sketched image of BB-8 against a ruled grid. Annotation as below]

The sketch on the cushion has an arrow labelled ***"Magnetic Balancing"***, pointing at where the head sits on the body.

Comment: +1 for invoking to the ubiquitous **this pillow** meme

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I'm always on the lookout for an opportunity to extend the meme.  Anything else you need for this answer?  :-)

Comment: *this pillow* meme?

Comment: @Praxis:  I believe you mean, *I'm always on the lookout for an opportunity to nag about acceptance*

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/the-many-memes-of-scifi-stackexchange/7677#7677

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Now, now.  ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Its my understanding that they actually made a working, patented roller-ball droid (besides the various props they created). It used MAGNETS, like everyone said.

[Here](https://www.google.com/patents/US8269447) appears to be the patent and [here](https://howbb8works.com/) is some more information.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE.  While your answer is interesting, we should point out that the question is asking for *in-universe* (i.e. how is BB-8 supposed to work from the point of view of the story).